# Якобы — союз, частица (пунктуация)

Tags: пунктуация

**1.**

> Прочитал, что, якобы, есть доказательства, что книгу Зогар написал вовсе не РаШБИ во II в., а Моше ди-Леон в XIII в., наверняка Вы встречали подобную критику.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что автор ошибочно обособил "якобы", ибо это частица в данном случае?
Да и присоединительный союз "якобы" никогда не обособляется (только перед союзом, с которого начинается присоединительная конструкция, запятая ставится).

**2.**

> Прочитал, якобы есть доказательства, что книгу Зогар написал вовсе не РаШБИ во II в., а Моше ди-Леон в XIII в., наверняка Вы встречали подобную критику.

А вот здесь "якобы" уже присоединительный союз?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не меняйте своего решения о принятии ответа, у нас так не принято. Я же специально написала, что это дополнительная информация, а не ответ. Пожалуйста, поставьте только стрелочку, а я вам за это тоже стрелочку поставлю ;)

Comment: А галочку о принятии моего ответа можно убрать?  Или это не получается? Галочка ставится только для одного ответа.

Comment: @Sharon  Стрелочка моя... А автор писал, что не может ставить стрелочки по каким-то техническим причинам.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец, все верно. Пользователь не может поставить галочку в связи с тем, что не может до конца зарегистрироваться на форуме.

Comment: Ничего себе, дела...  А вы, Александр, действуете по поручению. да :))

Comment: Каки-таки поручения? Я вам ставлю всегда (ну в 99 из 100)...

Comment: Галочку вернула на место, стрелочки недоступны, ибо зарегистрироваться не могу. Ошибка - и всё тут. Ven2ra, конечно же, благодарна! Как и Sharon! Я бы оба ответа приряла одновременно!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец,  Ну что тут сказать?  Воспользуюсь цитатой из другого вопроса: "Я тоже ценю хороших людей, которые встречаются мне в жизни". Не знаю только, есть ли тут нарушение синтаксических норм.

Comment: @Sharon, можно все свалить на семантическую часть :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Частица «**якобы**» выражает несоответствие действительности, предположение, сомнение в достоверности сказанного или происходящего. *Она используется в значении «будто бы», «как будто».*

Пример: *«Он сделал вид, что **якобы** занят». «Он сделал вид, что **будто бы** занят».*

Частица «якобы» придает эмоцию именно тому слову, к которому примыкает.

Говоря о союзе «**якобы**», можно отметить, что он заменяет слово "**что**".

Пример: *«Соседка клянется, **якобы** ничего не видела». «Соседка клянется, **что** ничего не видела».*

Если придаточная часть расположена в середине главного предложения, то первая запятая ставится перед союзом «якобы», а вторая — в конце придаточной части.

Пример: *«Вася считает, **якобы** он среди нас самый умный, и ничьих советов не слушает».*

Таким образом, как союз, так и частица - не обособляется. Исключение: придаточная часть.

Верное предложение звучит так: *Прочитал, **якобы есть доказательства**, что книгу Зогар написал вовсе не РаШБИ во II в., а Моше ди-Леон в XIII в., наверняка Вы встречали подобную критику.*

Comment: Глянула в Нацкорпус... Там ", что якобы..." - полно! И "якобы" в запятых с двух сторон есть. https://cutt.ly/zHRDcnD

Comment: @Катперкат, обратившись в Нацкорпус, ни одного обособления слово "якобы" не нашел. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, внимательнее.

Comment: Что, якобы, дети видели в тот вечер постороннего человека, сильно похожего на деда Мороза. [Марина Зосимкина. Ты проснешься. Книга первая (2015)]

Comment: @Катперкат, я увидел пример, он единственный. В остальных же случаях, слово «якобы» не обособляется — сами видите. Быть может, это ошибка автора.

Comment: Ну так правильно, что в первом моём примере "якобы" - частица, но неправильно взятая в запятые, а во втором - союз? Чисто формально...

Comment: @Катперкат, как союз, так и частица - не обособляются, за исключением придаточной части. Прочитать ответ Грамота.ру: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_775

Answer (score 3):

Первый ответ, безусловно, верен, я же просто добавлю информацию.

1. Союз «якобы» может заменять **изъяснительной союз** «что», но не во всех предложениях, и тогда **для ясности** используется сочетание союзов «что якобы», например:

Странно, странно, **что якобы** не знаешь…

Одним Смирнов говорил, что окончил университет, другим ― коммерческий институт, рассказывал, **что якобы** служил в частных банках, откровенничал, что играл на бирже.

2. Слово «якобы» может относиться к определительному или деепричастному **обороту**, тогда оно выступает в роли **присоединительного союза**.

Кроме того, есть проект строительства стекольного завода в Кольцово, **якобы высокорентабельного**.

Правда, в статье не были упомянуты имена создателей программы, после чего, **якобы обидевшись**, они уехали из Иллинойса в Кремниевую Долину.

3. Обособляется ли слово «якобы» в качестве **вводного слова?** Правилами это не разрешено, но в текстах такое написание встречается.

Что, **якобы**, дети видели в тот вечер постороннего человека, сильно похожего на деда Мороза.

Компания с наименованием, указанным в контракте, не существует в Швеции, не существует и адрес, по которому она, **якобы**, зарегистрирована.

Она, **якобы**, оставила дневник, в котором описала, как Адольф ее избивал в детстве.

Он, **якобы**, сразу подвернул ногу и начал усиленно хромать.

Он, **якобы**, прочитал их у купца Головастикова, а тот их потом продал на ярмарке.

Это **ошибка или авторская пунктуация**?

Посмотрим **синонимы** для «якобы»: *будто, будто бы, говорят, по слухам, прошел слух, слышно, считается.*

Некоторые синонимы похожи **на вводные слова**. Если  такая замена возможна, то можно считать обособление авторской пунктуацией. В этом случае слово «якобы» выделяется **интонационным ударением**: Он, якобы, прочитал…

Однако такая пунктуация потребует специального объяснения.